# What does the "and" keyword mean in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was typing a comment in Xcode, but forgot the leading `//`. I noticed that `and` was highlighted like a keyword. I did a bit of Googling, but I can't seem to figure out what it does (or even if it's a real keyword).

What does it mean?

Comment: It's an alternative for `&&`, IIRC.  (I think this is about the third time this question has come up in the past several months.)

Comment: @HotLicks But it's impossible to search for, because "and" is a search-engine keyword!

Comment: I found it once, by looking for "C keywords" or some such.

Comment: It is a macro and not a keyword.

Comment: @Cthutu - Did I ever say it's a "keyword"?

Comment: For anyone arguing, I believe *I* said it was a keyword in the question. Blame ambiguous syntax highlighting.

Comment: @HotLicks - It wasn't a response to your comment, but rather the original post.

Comment: Paul - Nah, this is a grudge match.  Oddly I find myself on H2CO3's side, though.  Usually he's the one picking nits.

Comment: @paulrehkugler it's a keyword in C++. Xcode compiles C++, amongst other things, and probably uses the same syntax highlighting rules for C, C++ and Objective-C. It therefore is quite likely highlighting it under its desire to highlight keywords, and giving zero regard to the exact means by which the token is defined in C and Objective-C. (EDIT: a source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and — I'm keeping out of the C debate)

Comment: @Tommy - I just checked what you said and you are very correct.  It is a reserved word in C++.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword for a complete list.  But it is not currently supported by Microsoft's compiler or Apple's.

Comment: @Cthutu Maybe the syntax highlighting is fixed now, because I just upgraded to the newest Xcode beta and it no longer highlights "and".

Comment: @paulrehkugler - I was surprised it highlighted in the first place because the syntax highlighter IS the same parser that the compiler uses in Xcode.  Perhaps a header like iso646.h was included indirectly by the usual framework headers.  And perhaps in the beta the and macro is not defined anywhere now.  I am glad your syntax highlighter is working well for you now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a synonym for `&&`. See [iso646.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h).

Answer (score 4):

It is not a keyword.  Objective-C shares exactly the same keywords as C with additional ones that always start with '@'.

EDIT: This question doesn't answer the original post (see Rob Napier's succint answer for this), but rather it highlights that 'and' is a macro in some standard library headers and not a reserved word.

Quote from the C standard (C11, n1570), page 58:

> 6.4.1 Keywords
>
> keyword: one of auto, break, case, ... [list of words not including 'and']